# NSTextView background not resizing appropriately

Tags: macos, cocoa, colors, nstextview

I have an NSTextView inside an NSScrollView.  The scroll view has the auto resize masks for height and width, so it changes size with the window it's in.

The text view is set up much in the way the apple documentation recommends [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextUILayer/Tasks/TextInScrollView.html).

But no matter what settings I put on the text view, I cannot get the background color to resize along with the scroll view.

Here's a picture of what I'm dealing with:

[image]

The width works, but not the height.

Here's my setup code for the textview as it is for this picture:

```
NSTextView *view = [[NSTextView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, scrollview.contentSize.width, scrollview.contentSize.height) textContainer:textContainer];
[view setMinSize:NSMakeSize(0.0, scrollview.contentSize.height)];
[view setMaxSize:NSMakeSize(FLT_MAX, FLT_MAX)];
[view setVerticallyResizable:YES];
[view setHorizontallyResizable:NO];
[view setAllowsDocumentBackgroundColorChange:YES];
[view setDrawsBackground:YES];
[view setAutomaticLinkDetectionEnabled:YES];
[view setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The white background colour isn’t that of the `NSTextView`, but rather that of its enclosing `NSScrollView`.

To change it, either select the NSScrollView in Interface Builder/Xcode 4. Or, to do it programmatically, use `-[NSView encosingScrollView]`:

```
NSScrollView *scrollView = [textView enclosingScrollView];
[scrollView setBackgroundColor:[NSColor blackColor]];
```